# What is the alternative to drupal_realpath()?

Tags: 7

I use [`drupal_realpath()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/drupal_realpath/7) to do includes for some code samples I have:

```
 require_once(drupal_realpath('public://php_includes/functions.php'));
```

This gives the real path `C:\www\sites\mysite\files\php_includes\functions.php`.
What is the command to get the HTTP path `http://mysite.com/sites/files/php_includes/functions.php`?

The api documentation says "RealPath is deprecated"... if it's deprecated, what is supposed to replace it to get the same path (either `C:\...` or `http://...`)?

Answer (score 6):

To get the HTTP path of a file, you need to use [`file_create_url($uri)`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/file_create_url/7).

```
file_create_url('public://php_includes/functions.php');
```

This will output `http://mysite.com/sites/files/php_includes/functions.php`.

Regarding the fact that [`drupal_realpath()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/drupal_realpath/7) is deprecated, I think it's to warn developers to avoid relying on file system path and instead use wrappers.

Comment: Does it works well with S3FS module?